# Evaluate function argument as string within dplyr custom function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

I am writing a custom function that outputs the mean and sd of a field. I would like the .field argument to be evaluated in a tidyeval manner at some states and as a string at another stage. **How can I evaluate the .field argument as a string?**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mean_sd <- function(.data, .field){
    .data %>% 
    summarise(
        mean = mean({{.field}}), 
        sd = sd({{.field}})
    ) %>% 
    pivot_longer(
        everything(),
        names_to = "stat",
        values_to = '.field' # I'd like this to print the value of .field
        ) %>% 
    mutate(across(is.numeric, ~round(.x, 2)))
}

mean_sd(mtcars, mpg)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the more elegant `rlang::englue` another option would be to use `as_label(enquo(x))`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

mean_sd <- function(.data, .field) {
  .data %>%
    summarise(
      mean = mean({{ .field }}),
      sd = sd({{ .field }})
    ) %>%
    pivot_longer(
      everything(),
      names_to = "stat",
      values_to = as_label(enquo(.field))
    ) %>%
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ round(.x, 2)))
}

mean_sd(mtcars, mpg)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   stat    mpg
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 mean  20.1 
#> 2 sd     6.03
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `as_label(enquo(x))` is exactly equivalent to `englue("{{ x }}")`, and how it's actually implemented :-)

Comment: Thx @LionelHenry for clarifying (and of course for all these nice features). Already guessed that. (:

Answer (score 6):

We can use `rlang::englue()` and use the curly curly operator inside:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mean_sd <- function(.data, .field){
  .data %>% 
    summarise(
      mean = mean({{.field}}), 
      sd = sd({{.field}})
    ) %>% 
    pivot_longer(
      everything(),
      names_to = "stat",
      values_to = rlang::englue("{{ .field }}")
    ) %>% 
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~round(.x, 2)))
}

mean_sd(mtcars, mpg)

#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   stat    mpg
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 mean  20.1 
#> 2 sd     6.03
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Updated code (thanks @TimTeaFan) who inspired me with his code!

We could use `rlang::quo_text(enquo(.field))` to get `.field` as string. But we have to wrap it around `as.character()` to convert the resulting expression to a character string.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mean_sd <- function(.data, .field){
  .data %>% 
    summarise(
      mean = mean({{.field}}), 
      sd = sd({{.field}})
    ) %>% 
    pivot_longer(
      everything(),
      names_to = "stat",
      values_to = as.character(rlang::quo_text(enquo(.field)))
    ) %>% 
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~round(.x, 2)))
}

mean_sd(mtcars, mpg)
```

```
  stat    mpg
  <chr> <dbl>
1 mean  20.1 
2 sd     6.03
```